# How to get applicationWillTerminate Notification for an iOS App that has Backgrounding Enabled?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, appdelegate

So I'm aware that `applicationWillTerminate:` will not be called if your app supports background execution (unless there's some memory issue), and `applicationDidEnterBackground:` is called instead.

Inside of the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method in the appDelegate, it says

```
// If your application supports background execution, 
//this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
```

However, I need to save some entries into a dictionary when the user actually quits the app. I do not want to do this every time the app enters the background though. Is there a way to get the termination notification even though my app supports backgrounding?

Specifically if the app is force quit by the user, what is some sort of workaround to get a notification of this?

Comment: A user never quits an app that supports background execution. The app simply enters the background. The app may be killed while in the background by the OS but that is not a user action. Why don't you want to save the data every time the app enters the background? That is your only option.

Comment: This is an app that interacts with an external bluetooth device. If the user force kills the app, I was under the impression that it is no longer in the background. Is this not the case?

Comment: This is true. If a user force kills an app, then your app gets no notification of any kind that it is being killed.

Comment: @maddy EDIT: nm, you answered my concern. I was highlighting the force quit issue

Comment: @rmaddy i'm not sure this is correct, at least not anymore. I use background locations, have them running fine in the background (see it in the console)... then i use the app-switcher to kill it... and i still get the applicationWillTerminate: notification.

Comment: @Gukki5 please see the documentation for applicationWillTerminate for the latest info. As of now it isn't called if the app is suspended in the background.

Comment: @rmaddy right right not for suspended. I meant, if you are live in the background, not suspended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save every time the app enters into the bg. the os may THEN kill you without any further warning.

Comment: here's my situation: the app connects to external bluetooth devices. If the app is killed, the bluetooth connection is killed and I need to save this fact for ui stuff when the app resumes. If the app is just backgrounded however, the bluetooth connection remains and I don't need to save anything. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: can't you see if its still up or not when the app resumes? e.g. something like if(connection.isValid) ... else ...

Comment: it takes a few seconds for it to reconnect after you resume the app. So basically i need the UI to be updated to this fact, but I don't want to update the UI when it just goes into the background (only when it terminates).